# jQuery.post() refreshing page in Firefox despite async: true

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my first post and I have the feeling that this is something stupid. I have already been to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511947?tab=newest#tab-top although that still did not really help.

I have 3 PHP pages. The main page is the one with all the jQuery on it:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // for each trade, load the current comparisons
            <?php
            foreach ($trades as $trade) {
                ?>
                $("#<?php echo $trade; ?>Div").load("functions/loadPriceSurveyComparisons.php", {
                    trade: "<?php echo $trade; ?>"
                });

                $("#addComp<?php echo $trade; ?>").click(function() {
                    $.post("functions/addPriceSurveyComparisons.php", {
                        trade: "<?php echo $trade; ?>",
                        alb: $("#albProd<?php echo $trade; ?>").val(),
                        comp: $("#compProd<?php echo $trade; ?>").val()
                    }, function(data) {
                        $("#<?php echo $trade; ?>Div").load("functions/loadPriceSurveyComparisons.php", {
                            trade: "<?php echo $trade; ?>"
                        });
                    }, "xml");
                });
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        });
    </script>
```

This page basically loads a list of items into div elements on load. $.load is used for this. The $.load has a callback which assigns click event handlers to 3 different HTML  elements (hence the PHP echo of $trade).

These click handlers basically do an AJAX request using $.post. The page being posted to is as follows:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
include("../includes/db_connection.php");
$sql = "INSERT INTO pricesurvey_compare (alb_product_id, comp_product_id, trade)
    VALUES (".$_POST['alb'].", ".$_POST['comp'].", '".$_POST['trade']."')";
mysql_query($sql);
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<data>
    <trade><?php echo $_POST['trade']; ?></trade>
    <alb><?php echo $_POST['alb']; ?></alb>
    <comp><?php echo $_POST['comp']; ?></comp>
    <errors><?php echo mysql_error(); ?></errors>
</data>
```

This jquery.post() request for some reason refreshes the page in Firefox and I'm not seeing any errors generated. I can't even view the request with firebug in the Net tab as when the page refreshes this is cleared. What's also interesting is that no javascript at all is appearing in the script tab? But that's another headache I'm not gonna pay attention to right now.

Please note that I am pretty much a noob when it comes to jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to add `e.preventDefault()`

```
$("#addComp<?php echo $trade; ?>").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Aaahhh, so the e.preventDefault() is in the click handler hey? :) Thanks, this works!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
return false;
```

right after the call to `$.post(...)` in your "click" handler. I don't know exactly what those "addComp" elements are, but if they're elements that cause the form to be submitted then your problem is that the form is being posted *twice*: once by your "click" handler, and once by ordinary browser form functionality.

Comment: sorry but this does not work. The problem was in the click handler. The "addComp" elements you were referring to were <button> elements

Comment: I said to do it in the click handler. That's what the phrase in my answer, "in your 'click' handler", means :-)  Returning `false` from an event handler does the same thing as calling `preventDefault()`, plus it also stops the "bubbling" of the event.