# div.load() causing full page postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

After saving form data, need to load the div only not whole page refresh but it first goes to Main Page Action Controller and then the DIV Load Partial Action Controller. I am unable to find the reason why it is posting whole page.

I have added the `preventDefault()` command too.

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = "@Url.Action("Save", "Note")";
    var id = "1";
    var model = {
      modelfields.....
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "True") {

              // Load div
                var settings = { editUrl: '@Url.Action("Get", "Note", new { ID = "-1" })' };
                 settings.editUrl = settings.editUrl.replace("-1", id);
                $("#divNoteDetails").load(settings.editUrl);
            }
            else if (data == "False") {
                alert('not saved');
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: what does the Note action return?

Comment: Both have `ActionResult ` as return type, Save is returning `ContentResult` while GetAction is returning `PartialView`

Comment: so your page is refreshing after you click the submit button?

Comment: If I add this div load command in ajax success, page is refreshing first then it goes to the partial view action. If I remove this  command it won't refresh. But I need to load div after saving the form.

Comment: Its a normal button not submit button

Comment: Have you tried to hook up some [error handling](http://api.jquery.com/load/) on the `load` function?

Comment: Also, [try/catch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/512159/6224482) around your AJAX call in order to catch any non-server errors.

Comment: Let me try this again

Answer (score 0):

if your button is inside a form then its default `type` is `submit`. [see the spec for details](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-button-type)

try adding `type="button"` to the button, or `event.preventDefault()` on an event handler attached to the form itself.

Comment: have you tried adding `preventDefault()` to the form `submit` handler?

Comment: I removed the forms but still this is happening